# batch file if statement error

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

How do I do this in a .bat batch file:

```
 if ("c:\program files\visualsvn server\bin\svnlook.exe" log -r2 d:\repositories\myrepo | findstr "~~DEPLOY~~" )
    (
     #dosomething
    )
    else
    (
     #dosomethingelse
    )
```

now I receive an error **log was unexpected at this time.**

Answer (score 2):

Use && and || to conditionally execute commands based on the success or failure of a previous command

```
"c:\program files\visualsvn server\bin\svnlook.exe" log -r2 d:\repositories\myrepo | findstr "~~DEPLOY~~" >nul && (
  #do_Something_If_Success
) || (
  #do_Something_Else_If_Failure
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set found_deploy=0
for /f 'eol=; tokens=1 delims=' %%c in ('"c:\program files\visualsvnserver\bin\svnlook.exe" log -r2 d:\repositories\myrepo ^| findstr "~~DEPLOY~~"') do (
    set found_deploy=1
)

if "!found_deploy!"=="1" (
    @REM::do_something_based_on_finding_deploy
) else (
    @REM::do_something_based_on_not_finding_deploy
)
```

Answer (score 1):

dbenham's answer assemble an IF-THEN-ELSE that is both advanced and criptic.
kikuchiyo's one is unnecessarily complicated.

This is a medium point between the previous two:

```
"c:\program files\visualsvn server\bin\svnlook.exe" log -r2 d:\repositories\myrepo | findstr "~~DEPLOY~~" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Deploy not found
) else (
    echo Deploy found
)
```